# Max retries exceeded > with url when attempting to use the Confluence rest API in python

Tags: python, windows, connection, port, confluence-rest-api

I trying to use the Confluence api with this code, its just a test to see if I can script creating a page in my confluence space in python.

```
from atlassian import Confluence

     confluence = Confluence(
           url='http://localhost:8090',
           username='admin',
           password='admin')

     status = confluence.create_page(
           space='DEMO',
           title='This is the title',
           body='This is the body. You can use <strong>HTML tags</strong>!')
 print(status)
```

For some reason I keep getting the error below. Any information is helpful. Google wasn't much help.

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8090): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /rest/api/content (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x0000028908E62A60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it'))

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to drop the port at the end. Once this was done the code exicuted.